# Python version doesn't change to 3.9

Tags: python, version

i install **python 3.9** but when i use python --version in terminal of Ubuntu i see my python **version is 2.7**
how can i change it ?!
[python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXcLf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would say that conventional wisdom says that you don't necessarily want to do this. Changing your default Python installation would create backwards compatibility issues with other scripts that invoke `python` where those scripts rely on Python 2x.  You can start Python 3 from the command line by using the `python3` command. If you still want to make the change, there are several posts on Stack Overflow that explain how to do this based on your platform.  Good luck.

Comment: i change it by this code :
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.9 2